# Primary reasons why programming language runtimes use stacks?

Tags: java, language-agnostic, programming-languages, stack

Many programming language runtime environments use stacks as their primary storage structure (e.g. see [JVM bytecode to runtime example](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/it-haggar_bytecode/)).

Quickly recalling I see following advantages:

- Simple structure (pop/push), trivial to implement
- Most processors are anyway optimized for stack operations, so it is very fast
- Less problems with memory fragmentation, it is always about moving memory-pointer up and down for allocation and freeing complete blocks of memory by resetting the pointer to the last entry offset.

Is the list complete or did I miss something? Are there programming language runtime environments which are not using stacks for storage at all?

Comment: Analogy w/ JVM aint good at all, actually processor are not designed for that type of flow.

Comment: Stacks have a simple allocation and de-allocation strategy.

Comment: what do you mean with 'type of flow': The above mentioned stack operations or the general runtime setup (frame design, constant-pool, local-var index, the flavor of op-instructions)? Many benchmarks of latest JVMs show quite good performance results...

Comment: @Peter: I guess with allocation/deallocation you mean the simple pointer moving up/down I mentioned? Or something else?

Comment: Something I'd like to see answered in this question:  How do functional languages handle the stack?  Along a similar line, with languages that use lambdas, how does the compiler handle closure for variables on the stack?

Comment: The jvm is on a par w/ C (seriously) -+5% performance, this is vastly due to optimization, cycle enrolling, method inlining, escape analysis and intrinsics, etc nothing to do w/ the stack layout of the class files. Putting data into the stack is virtually done only when calling not-optimized code (or deoptimized). Cliff Click who I linked can be quite a nice source for ideas.

Comment: Memory fragmentation is not resolved by using the stack at any rate either. JVM (and any other garbage enabled language) copy the memory, esp w/ tiered memory pools, to defragment.

Comment: Any claim that jvm is on par with C is a joke.

Comment: I don't necessarily disagree, but do you have something more to back that up?

Comment: @R: one more link from the same source Java vs C. I have my own tests as well but like I've told the source is very credible: http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff-click/2009-09-06-java-vs-c-performanceagain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just decided to include a link to one of the most insightful developers alive (and active), the architect of hotspot JVM:

> When you compare the speed & power of
>   a CPU executing bytecodes, you'll see
>   lots of hardware complexity around the
>   basic execution issues (I'm skipping
>   on lots of obvious examples, but
>   here's one: the stack layout sucks for
>   wide-issue because of direct stack
>   dependencies).

http://www.azulsystems.com/blog/cliff-click/2010-04-21-un-bear-able

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are runtimes that don't use stacks, or at least not the naive model with one stack and the CPU push/pop instructions. Newer languages designed for concurrency/multithreading commonly avoid the single-stack model. The Go language is an example.

One problem with the "hardware stack" is that error handling can be hard when the stack overflows (the handler may have to use stack space itself). Explicitly maintaining a stack in the heap, as a linked list perhaps, avoids this problem, although it means that stack overflow is reduced to heap overflow and an infinite recursion takes longer to detect.

Comment: What is the disadvantage of the stack-model? As far as I understood in Java each Thread has its own memory space where the frames are "layed out", so I don't quite understand the 'single' inside stack-model. Maybe you can give me reference? Maybe you know position Erlang takes here (it is supposed to be optimized for concurrency).

Comment: A stack is absolutely necessary for recursion, so any modern runtime uses one, or one per thread/task/whatever. The main problem with processor-supported stacks is their rigidity; they're dynamic arrays rather than linked structures, and inherit the advantages and disadvantages of arrays (e.g., stack overflow can occur even though there's still heap space where the next stack frame would fit if it weren't at the wrong address). I'm not very familiar with JVM internals, nor with Erlang. See http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#goroutines for heap-based stacks in Go.

Comment: Recursion is just deep--deep stack call line (deep stack line cannot solely use registers either). While the invocations can be partly inlined (talking about recursion), ultimately the stack is necessary. push/pop drops performances, of course, but it's necessary to implement recursive algorithms w/o converting the invocations into a loop w/ a stack on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

As methods can call other methods which may call others etc., and the storage for each must be maintained until the called method returns, using a stack frame to hold the storage is the obvious solution.

Answer (score 0):

Stack is also used to pass parameters between methods.  Typically the parameters will be pushed onto the stack by the caller and then callee will know where the parameters are in the stack (offsetting -ve from the current stack pointer).

Comment: That design w/ the stack is part of the old days, nowadays the CPUs have plenty of registers (+renaming) and the parameters are passed through the CPU registers.

Comment: Well, RISC processors have like 128+ registers, x86-64 (orx64) has 16GPR, IA64 has 128 (hopefully I am not outdated since it was many a year I used to do assembler). All of them, of course, allow renaming.